# File reading in c with fscanf

Tags: c, file, pointers

Im taking a class in c programming and I have this project where they give us a half-made project, and we need to finish it and fix some of the functions.
This project is about sort of a social network.
In this project you can send messages to other users (on the same computer for now) by writing the target user and then you enter the message. Afterwards the message is saved in a file called "messages.txt" in the same folder in this Format:
"[At]25/08/2013 [From]user1 [To]user2  [Message]hello whats up?"
"[At]Date [From]user [To]user2 [Message]any user input"
now after writing this, i go to the second user and try to read from the file with this function:

```
void showUnreadMessages(char* userName) // the function gets the name of the current 
user that wishes to read his/hers messages
{
    char msg[MAX_MESSAGE];
    char toU[MAX_USER_NAME];
    char fromU[MAX_USER_NAME];
    char at[15];
    int count = 0, flag = 0, count1 = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(MESSAGE_FILENAME, "rt"); //open the messages file
    FILE *temp;
    clearScreen(); //system("CLS")
    if (file == NULL) //if the file didn't exict open one
    {
        printf("No messages\n");
        flag = 1;
        _flushall();
        file = fopen(MESSAGE_FILENAME, "wt");
        _flushall();
    }
    while (!feof(file) && flag == 0) //if the file did exict
    {
        if (count1 == 0)
        {
            temp = file;
        }
        _flushall();
        fscanf(file, "[At]%s [From]%s [To]%s  [Message]%s\n", at, fromU, toU, msg); //scan one line at a time
        _flushall();
        if (strcmp(userName, toU) == 0) //if the userNames match than its a message for the current user
        {
            count++;
        }
        count1++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    if (count > 0 && flag == 0) //if there are messages to user
    {
        printf("You have %d new Messages\n", count);
        _flushall();
        while (!feof(temp))
        {
            _flushall();
            fscanf(temp, "[At]%s [From]%s [To]%s  [Message]%s\n", at, fromU, toU, msg); //scan one line at a time to print it for the user
            _flushall();
            if (strcmp(userName, toU) == 0)
            {
                printf("New message at %s from: %s\nStart of message: %s\n-----------------------------------------\n", at, fromU, msg);
            }
        }
        fclose(temp);
    }
    else if (count == 0 && flag == 0)
    {
        printf("You have no Messages\n");
    }
    if (!file)
    {
        remove(MESSAGE_FILENAME);
    }
    PAUSE; // system("PAUSE")
}
```

Now when i try to read with this function, it only shows that the message is the first word in the message section on the first line...
For example For "[At]25/08/2013 [From]user1 [To]user2  [Message]hello whats up?"
the message will be "hello"
and it will be printed twice.. i dont know what to do, for some reason when i open the file and do fscanf for one time it also shows that the pointer file starts "up?[At]... (what appears on the second line)"

Please help me if you understand what i did wrong (which i know is a lot)
Thanks in advance

Comment: `while(!feof())` is almost always wrong.

Comment: And `scanf` normally stops scanning at whitespace.  You probably want to choose a better method.

Comment: the scanf works, I don't know for the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of fscanf :

```
 "..etc.  [Message]%s\n"
```

will only read ONE word of "Hello what's up" because %s parses for contiguous characters.

```
nr_fields = fscanf(file, "[At]%s [From]%s [To]%s  [Message]%80c\n"
```

would read up to 80 characters regardless of spaces etc. in the text message.  Also, the destination for %80c must be 80 characters or more!

Also, always test for number of fields found by fscanf.

Finally, fscanf works when used as directed, but it does have some subtle aspects.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that `temp` is pointing to a handle that is no longer valid after you call `fclose(file)` after the first loop. You could use `fgets()` to read a line and `strtok()` and `strncpy()` to split the read string.

I think it would be a good idea to encapsulate the reading in an extra function to reduce code duplication.